# How to add an generated dynamic view to a root window using Infonode library?

Tags: java, jpanel, frame, dockpanel

i have a problem in using the infonode docking library. I have created the root window,dynamic view methods based on the example provided. Just modified it bit and just trying to use it. But I had gone through the documentations,user manuls provided by infonode. But coludnt find a way to add dynamic view to the rootwindow.

Here is an sampple code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sound.sampled.ReverbType;
import javax.swing.*;

import net.infonode.docking.*;
import net.infonode.docking.drag.DockingWindowDragSource;
import net.infonode.docking.drag.DockingWindowDragger;
import net.infonode.docking.drag.DockingWindowDraggerProvider;
import net.infonode.docking.util.DockingUtil;
import net.infonode.docking.util.MixedViewHandler;
import net.infonode.docking.util.ViewMap;




public class DockTrial extends JFrame
{

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu fileMenu;
    JMenuItem fMI;
    int counter=0;
    CustomRootWindow cRootWin;

     private static final int ICON_SIZE = 8;
    /**
       * Contains the dynamic views that has been added to the root window
       */
      private HashMap dynamicViews = new HashMap();

      /**
       * The one and only root window
       */
      private RootWindow rootWindow;

      /**
       * Contains all the static views
       */
      private ViewMap viewMap = new ViewMap();

      /**
       * An array of the static views
       */
      private View[] views = new View[3];

      /**
       * A dynamically created view containing an id.
       */
      private static class DynamicView extends View {
        private int id;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param title     the view title
         * @param icon      the view icon
         * @param component the view component
         * @param id        the view id
         */
        DynamicView(String title, Icon icon, Component component, int id) {
          super(title, icon, component);
          this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the view id.
         *
         * @return the view id
         */
        public int getId() {
          return id;
        }
      }


    public DockTrial()
    {
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Docktrial");
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(menuBarr());
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        createComponents();
        assignfunctions();
        add(createToolBar(),BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        getContentPane().add(rootWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void createComponents()
    {
         // Create the views
        for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
          views[i] = new View("View " + i, VIEW_ICON, createViewComponent("View " + i));
          viewMap.addView(i, views[i]);
        }

        // The mixed view map makes it easy to mix static and dynamic views inside the same root window
        MixedViewHandler handler = new MixedViewHandler(viewMap, new ViewSerializer() {
          public void writeView(View view, ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(((DynamicView) view).getId());
          }

          public View readView(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException {
        return getDynamicView(in.readInt());
          }
        });

        rootWindow = DockingUtil.createRootWindow(viewMap, handler, true);
    }

    public void assignfunctions()
    {
    fMI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        /*  FloatingWindow fw = rootWindow.createFloatingWindow(new Point(50, 50),
                new Dimension(300, 200),
                getDynamicView(getDynamicViewId()));

                // Show the window
                fw.getTopLevelAncestor().setVisible(true);
                fw.isDockable();*/

                /*getDynamicView(getDynamicViewId()).dock();
                rootWindow.revalidate();*/
        }
    });
    }

     /**
       * Creates the frame tool bar.
       *
       * @return the frame tool bar
       */
      private JToolBar createToolBar() {
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Drag New View");
        toolBar.add(label);
        new DockingWindowDragSource(label, new DockingWindowDraggerProvider() {
          public DockingWindowDragger getDragger(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        return getDynamicView(getDynamicViewId()).startDrag(rootWindow);
          }
        });
        return toolBar;
      }

     /**
       * Returns a dynamic view with specified id, reusing an existing view if possible.
       *
       * @param id the dynamic view id
       * @return the dynamic view
       */
      private View getDynamicView(int id) {
        View view = (View) dynamicViews.get(new Integer(id));

        if (view == null)
          view = new DynamicView("Dynamic View " + id, VIEW_ICON, createViewComponent("Dynamic View " + id), id);

        return view;
      }

    /**
       * Returns the next available dynamic view id.
       *
       * @return the next available dynamic view id
       */
      private int getDynamicViewId() {
        int id = 0;

        while (dynamicViews.containsKey(new Integer(id)))
          id++;

        return id;
      }

    /**
       * Returns a dynamic view with specified id, reusing an existing view if possible.
       *
       * @param id the dynamic view id
       * @return the dynamic view
       */
      private View getDynamicView(int id ,String t) {
        View view = (View) dynamicViews.get(new Integer(id));

        if (view == null)
          view = new DynamicView("Dynamic View " + id + t, VIEW_ICON, createViewComponent("Dynamic View " + id), id);

        return view;
      }


      /**
       * Creates a view component containing the specified text.
       *
       * @param text the text
       * @return the view component
       */
      private static JComponent createViewComponent(String text) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
          sb.append(text + ". This is line " + j + "\n");

        return new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(sb.toString()));
      }

      /**
       * Custom view icon.
       */
      private static final Icon VIEW_ICON = new Icon() {
        public int getIconHeight() {
          return ICON_SIZE;
        }

        public int getIconWidth() {
          return ICON_SIZE;
        }

        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
          Color oldColor = g.getColor();

          g.setColor(new Color(70, 70, 70));
          g.fillRect(x, y, ICON_SIZE, ICON_SIZE);

          g.setColor(new Color(100, 230, 100));
          g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, ICON_SIZE - 2, ICON_SIZE - 2);

          g.setColor(oldColor);
        }
      };

    public JMenuBar menuBarr()
    {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fMI = new JMenuItem("New Tab");
        fileMenu.add(fMI);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new DockTrial();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am evaluating this framework too. The answer is using DockingUtil.addwindow. Here is the sample.

```
  public TestFrame() {
        super("Test Dock");
        rw = new RootWindow(null);
        JMenu mu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("Add Dock");
        mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View vw = new View("Dock", null, new JLabel("test"));
                DockingUtil.addWindow(vw, rw);
            }
        });
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mu.add(mi);
        mb.add(mu);
        this.setJMenuBar(mb);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(rw);

    }
```